# FullCalendar won't collapse within Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, fullcalendar

I am trying to get fullCalendar to open when a user clicks on a toggle button I am using with Bootstrap 3. The calendar works fine if the button default is open when the page is loaded but I want the calendar to be closed when the page loads and I can't get the calendar to open from a default of closed.
I have made up a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/vwL7q/10/)

Here is the html.

```
<div class="container">  
    <br />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" 
        data-target="#toggleDemo" value="Calendar" />
    <!-- Collapsible Element HTML -->
    <div id="toggleDemo" class="collapse collapse in">
        <div id='calendar'></div>
    </div>
    <br />
```

And here is the Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    // put your options and callbacks here
})

});
```

I hope someone can shed some light on my problem. Many thanks.

JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html:

```
<div class="container">  
   <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggleDemo" value="Calendar">

<!-- Collapsible Element HTML -->
<div id="toggleDemo" class="collapse collapse">
    <div id="calendar">

    </div>   
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    })

    $('#toggleDemo').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('today');
    });


});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/GB8DF/